# How to get number of rows on a result

Tags: c, sqlite

I execute a statement on sqlite3 in c and I want to get the number of rows the result has.

I saw that the **sqlite3_exec** has a param for a callback that receives such info, but im using **sqlite3_prepare_v2** and it seems not having such callback.

I can't find any function to retrieve the number of rows, so how is it done?

NOTES:

A) no, I don't want to use `select count(*)`, I expect there is something in the API that I'm missing.

B) no, I don't want to iterate all the rows and count. It is slow and spoils the row fetching system.

Comment: Call `sqlite3_step()` until it returns `SQLITE_DONE` or a non-recoverable error, incrementing a counter each time it returns `SQLITE_ROW`. It doesn't know ahead of time how many rows a query is going to return.

Comment: I was in fear that it was the matter. That is the B solution I coded but, the problem is that I have to reset the result to fetch it afterwards. 
The statemachine inside the sqlite3 seems to broke if there are calls to sqlite3_* functions.

Comment: You should show your code.`sqlite3_reset()` is used to reset a given statement so it starts from the first row again (possibly with different bound parameters). It shouldn't be used if you're not done with a given result set yet.

Comment: What is wrong with `select count(*)`?

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to use `count(*)` it's probably your best option. Sqlite gives you an iterator, there's no way to know how many results are there until you walk it.

Comment: I was expecting there were some "sqlite_get_the_number_of_rows()" function that could get the value. Using another query makes the connector I'm building more complex.

Comment: @Shawn after reseting the result it seems I was forgetting to make another step, as the prepare_v2 requires. It works now, but I find the "step, reset, iterate, reset, step" kinda cumbersome and slow on mobile devices just to get the number of rows